# The expected value of a double exponential function of normal random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $x$ be a random variable from a normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma)$.  How do we calculate the expectation $E[e^{k\cdot e^{-x}}]$, where $k<0$?

I think we can use the moment generating function

$
E[e^{k\cdot e^{-x}}] = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^{t}E[e^{-tx}]}{t!}
$, where $E[e^{-tx}]=e^{-t\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}t^{2}}$

But is there a more "compact" solution beyond the one above?